# Association Mapping on self referencing table with Cross reference table

Tags: php, symfony

I'm little confused about, how to add an association mapping, for my problem, in symfony.

i have two entities: User and Friends.

The user table has a id as primary key (auto).
The friends table has a id(auto,primary key), userId and friendId as columns.
The friendId is also an user in the User table.

Friends Table:

```
ID  userId    friendsId
---------------------
1    564          123
2    564          345
3    777          456


User Table:
ID  Name
---------------------
123  Alfons
345  Paul
456  Guiseppe
564  Mary
777  Belinda
```

Now i want to map the two tables, that i can call a function in my Userobject e.g let's say `getFriends(): User`. This function should return the Usersobjects referencing to the friends table where my user's id is stored.

The right way should be a One-To-Many Association, Unidirectional with Join Table?

Thank you in advance;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the entities's fields should look like

**In User Entity Class**

```
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;        


    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Friend", mappedBy="friendUser")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User")
     */
    private $friends;
```

**In Friend Entity Class**

```
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * This is the user
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="ID")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="ID")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * This is the friends' user entity
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="ID")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="friendsId", referencedColumnName="ID")
     */
    private $friendUser;
```